# Child routes in named outlet

Tags: javascript, angular

i want make child routes in router outlet.

Is it possible to make it? I want to make modal window with changeable url and think make it with named outlet. I expect it will be like `/(modal:auth)/step1`.

For example i made plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/vXvTHJF2KsCUkdvujzsn?p=preview

How i can open children greeting in auth component?

How will be right implement router?

```
export const authRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent,
    outlet: 'modal',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'greeting',
        component: StepComponent,
        outlet: 'modal'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: If you want them in the same outlet, why not make brothers ?

Comment: @trichetriche in example i want make step-by-step auth and i need main component, which will be watch for state in each one

Comment: If it's step by step, then maybe you should use a service ? A service can be shared across components, it should be easier to use it

Comment: Hmm, you right for this case, but in my case is not only step-by-step, some child components can be skipped and etc.. I think, what will be more suitable option to use main component for child routes..

Comment: I think you're overthinking it. A simple route, with all your children in it, and a service should be enough. But to answer you, I don't think it's possible for a child to have the same outlet as his parent. How would he be displayed otherwise?

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is really true, i will try it. Thank you!